# What kind of connection allows rotation at only one end?

Tags: statics, dynamics, bearings

We are looking to connect a non spinning coolant pipe to a spinning drill pipe. The connector needs to spin on the end with the drill pipe but be stationary on the end with the coolant pipe. Is there some type of bearing you know of or some other connector?

Comment: This is categoriacally known as a bearing. One pipe will usually be larger than the other and concentric to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OP is asking about transferring fluid (coolant) through a rotating joint.

These kinds of joints are called [rotary unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_union) or swivel joints. One end of the rotary union is stationary, the other end may rotate continuously, and fluid passes through the joint, which is sealed even when the joint is in motion.

Comment: yes exactly what I was looking for thanks @Chuck